# How to use to two different programs into one stkech

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, programming, switch, charging

I am currently using relay module, but I am facing a problem that, when Arduino pins are LOW then all relay are going HIGH, so I want to use this code so that when arduino starts all pins are getting HIGH, and also can be control with char data/switch(data)/case break;/,

```
Here is my code:

setup() {
  if(conditionIsTrue) {
    aGroup::setup();
  } else {
    bGroup::setup();    
  }
}

loop() {
  if(conditionIsTrue) {
    aGroup::loop();
  } else {
    bGroup::loop();    
  }
}

namespace aGroup {
setup() {

    pinMode(ledPinA, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(ledPinB, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(ledPinC, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(ledPinD, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(ledPinE, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(ledPinF, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(ledPinG, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(ledPinH, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(ledPinI, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(ledPinJ, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(ledPinK, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(ledPinL, OUTPUT);

}

loop() {

  digitalWrite(ledPinA, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(ledPinB, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(ledPinC, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(ledPinD, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(ledPinE, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(ledPinF, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(ledPinG, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(ledPinH, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(ledPinI, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(ledPinJ, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(ledPinK, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(ledPinL, HIGH);

}
}

namespace bGroup {
setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(ledPinA, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(ledPinB, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(ledPinC, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(ledPinD, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(ledPinE, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(ledPinF, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(ledPinG, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(ledPinH, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(ledPinI, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(ledPinJ, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(ledPinK, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(ledPinL, OUTPUT);

}

loop() {

  char data = Serial.read();
    switch(data) 
    {
        case 'A': digitalWrite(ledPinA, HIGH);break;
        case 'B': digitalWrite(ledPinA, LOW);break;

        case 'C': digitalWrite(ledPinB, HIGH);break;
        case 'D': digitalWrite(ledPinB, LOW);break;

        case 'E': digitalWrite(ledPinC, HIGH);break;
        case 'F': digitalWrite(ledPinC, LOW);break;

        case 'G': digitalWrite(ledPinD, HIGH);break;
        case 'H': digitalWrite(ledPinD, LOW);break;

        case 'I': digitalWrite(ledPinE, HIGH);break;
        case 'J': digitalWrite(ledPinE, LOW);break;

        case 'K': digitalWrite(ledPinF, HIGH);break;
        case 'L': digitalWrite(ledPinF, LOW);break;

        case 'M': digitalWrite(ledPinG, HIGH);break;
        case 'N': digitalWrite(ledPinG, LOW);break;

        case 'O': digitalWrite(ledPinH, HIGH);break;
        case 'P': digitalWrite(ledPinH, LOW);break;

        case 'Q': digitalWrite(ledPinI, HIGH);break;
        case 'R': digitalWrite(ledPinI, LOW);break;

        case 'S': digitalWrite(ledPinJ, HIGH);break;
        case 'T': digitalWrite(ledPinJ, LOW);break;

        case 'U': digitalWrite(ledPinK, HIGH);break;
        case 'V': digitalWrite(ledPinK, LOW);break;

        case 'W': digitalWrite(ledPinL, HIGH);break;
        case 'X': digitalWrite(ledPinL, LOW);break;


    }

}
}
```

But this isn't work, Please help me.

Comment: The title seems to bear absolutely no relation to the question. Could you edit one or the other so that they match, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In first place, you have to declare the functions setup and loop as `void setup()` and `void loop()`.

If you want your output pins to be high when Arduino starts then you should do that in your setup function, instead of doing it in the loop:

```
void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);

  // Step 1: configure pins as outputs
  pinMode(ledPinA, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledPinB, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledPinC, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledPinD, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledPinE, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledPinF, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledPinG, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledPinH, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledPinI, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledPinJ, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledPinK, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledPinL, OUTPUT);

  // Step 2: initialize pins to output HIGH
  digitalWrite(ledPinA, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(ledPinB, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(ledPinC, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(ledPinD, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(ledPinE, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(ledPinF, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(ledPinG, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(ledPinH, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(ledPinI, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(ledPinJ, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(ledPinK, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(ledPinL, HIGH);
}
```

Also, you can't declare a variable and assign to it the value of a function other than an object constructor. Furthermore, you should check if there's data available before trying to read it. So you have replace the following sentence:

```
char data = Serial.read();
```

With something like this:

```
char data = 0;
if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    data = Serial.read();
    // do your stuff
}
```

This should do the trick.

Last but not least: I don't know why you're using two `namespace`s. The `aGroup` looks useless to me. On top of that, I fail to see where in your code do you declare, initialise and update the `conditionIsTrue` variable. The same goes for all those `ledPinX` variables. Is there more code that you're not showing here? Is your code failing at runtime, or doesn't even compile?

Comment: YES SIR, it is working very good........ Thanks a lot.......